# install/uninstall ASUS USB-AC56 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, asus, realtek-wireless, additional-drivers

I just bought a USB-AC56 Asus dual-band wirless-ac 1300 adapter. It works out of the box for Windows. But on Ubuntu you need to install the drivers.

the output of lsusb relevant to the adapter:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:17d2 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-AC56 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8812AU]
```

I was told by Asus to use the following:
https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/USB-AC56/DR_USB_AC56_425_Linux.zip. How do I install the drivers? Asus gives no further instructions besides the link nor a way to uninstall.

I also read that the following github project might work better:
https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU

Are these drivers better? Are they even the right one? I don't want to install something that I cannot undo. Does anyone know how to uninstall the dkms package?

Is this correct?

```
$ DRV_NAME=rtl8812AU
$ DRV_VERSION=4.3.20
$ sudo dkms remove ${DRV_NAME}/${DRV_VERSION} --all
```

Please help verify what needs to be done for us all!

Comment: Please edit to include result from terminal for `lsusb`

Comment: First, let's confirm your exact device. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`

Comment: Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:17d2 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-AC56 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8812AU]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the best method is to obtain an internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
sudo modprobe 88XXau
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: This is for the usb wireless adapter? and how to uninstall? If I don't have my usb-wireless adapter plugged in will it revert to my original wireless adapter?

Comment: This will not interfere with your other wifi adapter, it will work for your AC56

Comment: Thanks!! I have two connections now, it appears. They can't both connect to the same network. how do I disable the original network card? I tried iwconfig but what do I do after that?

Comment: I think the command is: iwconfig, find the name of the adapter: x. Then sudo ifconfig x down. I believe this is temporary?

Comment: If you wish to permanently disable the internal card, we can blacklist its driver. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, any hints on how to blacklist wlo1?

Comment: Just a note on the current version of that Github repository:  The command `sudo ./dkms-install` and everything after it has been replaced with `sudo make dkms_install`.  Also, if you then get an error about a missing close-parenthesis, add a '\' before the `#define` on line 2300.

Comment: Thanks @IronEagle! I didn't run into the typo, but I needed that make command. I updated the answer as well :)